# How to prove that if two functions are of exponential order their product and sum are also of exponential order?

Tags: proof-writing, laplace-transform

How to prove that if $F_1(t)$ and $F_2(t)$ are of exponential order when $t \to\infty$, therefore $F_1(t) \cdot F_2(t)$ and $F_1(t) + F_2(t)$ are also of exponential order when $t \to\infty$?

I know that a function F(t) is of exponential order if for constants c > 0 and M >0, there exists T > 0 such that |F(t)| $\leqslant Me^{ct}$ for t > T.

Now, for the first part of the proof I did this:

> Let $F_1(t)$ and $F_2(t)$ be of exponential order. For $M_1, M_2, c_1, c_2 >0:$
>   $|F_1(t)|\leqslant M_1 e^{c_1t}$
>   $|F_2(t)|\leqslant M_2 e^{c_2t}$
>   $|F_1(t)| \cdot |F_2(t)| \leqslant M_1 e^{c_1t} \cdot M_2 e^{c_2t}$
>   $|F_1(t) \cdot F_2(t)| \leqslant M_1  \cdot M_2 \cdot e^{(c_1 + c_2)t}$

Since $M_1, M_2, c_1, c_2 >0$, then $M_1  \cdot M_2 > 0$ and $c_1 + c_2 > 0$ .
This means that if $F_1(t)$ and $F_2(t)$ are of exponential order when $t \to\infty$, therefore $F_1(t) \cdot F_2(t)$ is also of exponential order.

When I try to apply the same procedure to $F_1(t) + F_2(t)$ I end up with this:
$|F_1(t)| + |F_2(t)| \leqslant M_1  \cdot e^{c_1t} + M_2 \cdot e^{c_2t}$

Where do I go from here?

I want to get something of the form $|F_1(t) + F_2(t)| \leqslant Me^{ct}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1: Use the triangle inequality to relate $|F_1(t) + F_2(t)|$ to $|F_1(t)| + |F_2(t)|$.

Hint 2: Now you have $M_1 e^{c_1 t} + M_2 e^{c_2 t}$. Since we only care about large $t$, we can simply focus on the one with the bigger exponent. Let's consider the case $c_1 > c_2$. Show that there is some constant $M'_2$ such that $M_2 e^{c_2 t} \le M'_2 e^{c_1 t}$ for all large $t$. Then you have $M_1 e^{c_1 t} + M_2 e^{c_2 t} \le (M_1 + M'_2) e^{c_1 t}$.